# How to connect Angular app with SignalR server through Backend for Frontend

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I have Angular app, the BFF written in ASP NET Core, and SignalR hub. From Angular app, I want to send request to BFF endpoint, which will extract access token from cookie and then redirect the request to valid SignalR hub.

But the problem is that when I do redirect to SignalR hub through my BFF, then after successful negotiation my Angular app wants to talk with my BFF, instead of SignalR server.

```
public static async Task<IResult> GetChatHubInfo(HttpContext context, string negotiateVersion, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var accessToken = context.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

    context.Response.Headers.Authorization = $"Bearer {accessToken}";
    return Results.Redirect($"https://localhost:7271/negotiate?negotiateVersion={negotiateVersion}", preserveMethod: true);
}
```

Comment: SignalR uses WebSockets, not HTTP. It uses its own protocol, it's not an HTTP API that can be wrapped by another HTTP API. Why don't you use the JavaScript SignalR client to talk to a hub that provides just the calls needed by your front end?

Comment: 1. Because my BFF must extract the access token from cookie. I theoretically could extract the token from cookie, and return it back to the Angular app, but I use BFF to not show access token to my frontend. 2. Btw. I found a workaround, I can use 307 redirect which will preserve the HTTP method, but it didnt work because after successfully connection my Angular app wants to talk with my BFF, instead directly to SignalR server. I will edit my question and modify code.

Comment: Instead `successful connection` I meant `successful negotiation`

Comment: BFF doesn't explain anything. It only says you've created page-specific APIs. You can create page-specific SignalR hubs too. SignalR uses the *same* authentication as the rest of ASP.NET Core, so there shouldn't be any reason to redirect. How *did* you configure the SignalR hub? Have you checked the [Authentication and authorization in ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0) page, especially the `Bearer Token` and `JWT`sections?

Comment: But my SignalR hub is not part of BFF. Its external microservice (I mean different domain), and there are many SignalR servers which integrates using redis backplane.

Comment: Just because you use Redis doesn't mean the hubs should be in a different service or that your web API can't also use SignalR.

Comment: While designing I thought like it: one BFF, multiple SignalR servers. Do you think that shall I have combined BFF and SignalR? It means that I would need to host new BFF instance if I want to scale SignalR. It seems strange for me because the BFF just serves Angular SPA and manages authentication.

Comment: You keep using BFF as if it's something more than a fashion term. It's not. It's not a specification, it doesn't mean you should use HTTP only and doesn't explain *anything* about your design. It's like saying `bell bottoms`. You can have cotton and synthetic ones, long ones, short ones, narrow and wide ones.

Comment: But the BFF does simple things like caching, calling another microservices, auth while the SignalR hub is intensively used for messaging. I think they have different scalling needs and that's why I see it strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using reversed proxy built with YARP. That's my configuration:

```
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "ChatHub": {
        "ClusterId": "ChatHub",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/api/chathub/{*any}"
        },
        "Transforms": [
          {
            "PathRemovePrefix": "/api/chathub"
          },
          {
            "RequestHeadersCopy": true
          },
          {
            "RequestHeaderOriginalHost": true
          },
          {
            "RequestHeader": "Upgrade",
            "Set": "WebSocket"
          },
          {
            "RequestHeader": "Connection",
            "Set": "Upgrade"
          },
          {
            "RequestHeaderRemove": "Cookie"
          },
          {
            "X-Forwarded": "Set",
            "For": "Append",
            "Proto": "Append",
            "Prefix": "Append",
            "HeaderPrefix": "X-Forwarded-"
          },
        ]
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "ChatHub": {
        "SessionAffinity": {
          "Enabled": true,
          "Policy": "HashCookie",
          "FailurePolicy": "Redistribute",
          "AffinityKeyName": "ChatHubAffinityKey",
          "Cookie": {
            "HttpOnly": true,
            "IsEssential": true,
            "SameSite": "Strict",
            "SecurePolicy": "Always"
          }
        },
        "LoadBalancingPolicy": "PowerOfTwoChoices",
        "Destinations": {
          "ChatHub/Dest1": {
            "Address": "https://localhost:7140"
          },
          "HealthCheck": {
            "Active": {
              "Enabled": true,
              "Interval": "00:00:15",
              "Timeout": "00:00:10",
              "Policy": "ConsecutiveFailures",
              "Path": "/health"
            },
            "Passive": {
              "Enabled": true,
              "Policy": "TransportFailureRate",
              "ReactivationPeriod": "00:00:15"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

As u see, I remove every cookie while proxying. I have written the logic to extract the access token where I configure proxy, like that:

```
services.AddReverseProxy()
    .LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"))
    .AddTransforms(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddRequestTransform(async (ctx) =>
        {
            var accessToken = await ctx.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
            ctx.ProxyRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
        });
    });
```